# CSS background position giving different results between browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, background

IE don't seem to know what bottom means... I'm trying to position background svg in the bottom center of the div. 
[screen shot comparing IE and Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpvNX.png)

http://codepen.io/g_am1/pen/KdrvbZ

```
<div id="pixels">
  <p><code>background-position: </code></p>
</div>

<div id="percentages">
  <p><code>background-position: </code></p>
</div>

<div id="keywords">
  <p><code>background-position: </code></p>
</div>
```

and

```
div {
  width: 800px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid #E18728;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
  background: url(http://ridebike.ws/images/other/bikesenerey.svg); 
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#pixels { background-position: 350px 0; }

#percentages { background-position: 50% 100%; }

#keywords { background-position: bottom center; }


/* styling for Pen, unrelated to background-position */
p { 
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```

Comment: Check your SVG's `preserveAspectRatio` option. Sounds like you want it set to `none`? SVGs have some settings when being saved in Illustrator and PS that IE reads incorrectly. Your positioning works fine with other standard SVG images. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epQGpb

Comment: yes! we are on the right track but "none" stretches the svg to the top of the div. I want it to appear along the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMax meet"